# how to set meson link dependency for buildin lib as "-lm -lrt"

Tags: meson-build

on meson build, dependencies are resolved by pkg-config/cmake ...

but for system libs, no docs.  I only find 2 of them:

- **zlib** stands for -lz
- **threads** stands for -lpthread

then how can I link -lm -lrt ?

- "m"
- "math"
- "libm"
- runtime

all guess fail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ok, method found in doc:

```
cc = meson.get_compiler('c')
m_dep = cc.find_library('m', required : false)
executable("abc", dependencies : m_dep)
```

for common libs that's not good design. 
why not make it easy? such as:

> m_dep = dependency('m', method : 'build-in')

Comment: One can have a different version of the library depending on the compiler, especially when cross-compiling.

Answer (score 0):

May be simpler to use the link_args keyword as in:

```
executable('abc', link_args : '-lm -lrt')
```